# Are there long arithmetic progressions non-coprime with the given number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there positive integers $q$, $n$, $d$ such that $q\perp n$ and
$$
q,\ q+n,\ q+2n,\,\ldots\, q+(d-1)n
$$

are all **not** coprime to $d$?

I believe there are not, but so far I couldn't prove it. Numerical search (up to ~400) seems to support this claim. There are well-known results concerning distribution of prime numbers in such progression (Dirichlet's theorem says it contains infinitely many primes, Linnik's theorem gives a lower bound on the size of the first one), but none seems directly applicable.

I haven't made any significant progress, I've just proven few trivialities. Suppose there exist such numbers. Then let
$$
q+rn = s_r\mod d
$$
and $d_r=\gcd\left(s_r, d\right)$.

- If $p\mid s_r$, $p\mid n$, then $p\mid q$, and so $p=1$, hence $d_r$ and $n$ are always coprime.
- Residues are not coprime to $d$, hence at least two of them are equal:
  $$
  (r-s)\,n=0\mod d
  $$
  and since $\left|r-s\right|<d$, it follows that $n$ and $d$ are not coprime.
- if $q+rn=0\  \mbox{mod } d$, $r\neq 0$, then $\gcd\left(n, d\right)\mid q$, which contradicts $n\perp q$
- $s_r$, $s_{r+1}$ are coprime, since a common divisor would divide their difference - $n$, but then it cannot divide $q$, and so is not a divisor of $q+rn=s_r$.
- Consequently, $d_r$ and $d_{r+1}$ are coprime.

Still, it's just a messy bunch of observations.

Comment: What does ⊥ mean in this case?

Comment: @kingW3 $a\perp b$ means $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. Assuming that I correctly interpreted it as claiming that at least one of the numbers in the progression is coprime to $d$.

Factor $d=d_1d_2$ in such a way that in the prime factorizations
$$d_1=\prod_ip_i^{a_i},\qquad d_2=\prod_jq_j^{b_j}$$
we have $p_i\mid n$ for all $i$, and $q_j\nmid n$ for all $j$.

Here $\gcd(n,d_2)=1$, so the numbers in the progression $q+in, 0\le i<d_2$ are all pairwise incongruent modulo $d_2$. Therefore one of them, say $q+i_0n$, is congruent to $1\pmod {d_2}$. I claim that $m=q+i_0n$ is coprime to $d$. We cannot have $p_i\mid m$ for any $i$, as then we would also have $p_i\mid q$ violating the condition that $q$ and $n$ must be coprime. But we cannot have $q_j\mid m$ either, because $m\equiv 1\pmod{q_j}$ for all $j$.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the kind of proof I expected.I believe the inequality in $0\leq i<d_2-1$ should not be sharp, am I right?

Comment: Yup. There was a typo there. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 0):

Well take
$$q=kd+n\\q+(d-1)n=kd+n+(d-1)n=dn+kd=d(k+n)$$
Note $n \not\mid kd$,I guess this is the solution you could try replacing those numbers and checking if it adds up(I currently got no time to do so)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't follow. If $q=kd+n$ and $p\mid q$, $p\mid d$, then $p\mid n$, and $q$, $n$ are not coprime. Also, what about, say, $q+n$? I don't see an obvious common divisor of $q+n$ and $d$. What am I missing?

Comment: Well one of $p\mid q$ or $p \mid d$ has to be incorrect.I thought you were looking that any of the is not co-prime not that all are co-prime.Anyway let me think a bit,i'll try to come up with a solution.